# What changes to make to this monolith Kconfig Wifi Driver File to Compile it as a Module ? Right Now , When using Cmake , No Ko file is generated

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

[image]

This is the current Kconfig File and make file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your kernel version is 5.12 or greater, you're apparently looking at a file in Linux kernel source code package, with pathname `<kernel source root>/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt7921/Kconfig`. This is a file that provides information to the process that *produces* the actual kernel configuration file. Modifying this file won't actually change the kernel configuration.

The text "To compile this driver as a module, choose M here" is a help text for the respective kernel configuration menu option: you can see the kernel configuration menu by running e.g. `make menuconfig` in the `<kernel source root>` directory. The `make menuconfig` command will process all the `Kconfig` files in the various parts of the kernel source directory tree, and use the data to build a kernel configuration menu, which it will present to you.

The kernel configuration file is at `<kernel source root>/.config`, respectively.

To compile this driver as a module, you should find a line in `<kernel source root>/.config` that says either:

```
# CONFIG_MT7921E is not set
```

or:

```
CONFIG_MT7921E=y
```

and change that line to:

```
CONFIG_MT7921E=m
```

If the `CONFIG_MT7921E` line does not exist in the `.config` file, you can just add it.

But I don't understand what you mean with "when using Cmake, no .ko file is generated". Normally, you're supposed to run `make modules`, `make all` or one of the other Makefile targets while `cd`'d to your `<kernel source root>` directory.

(There is a command named `cmake`, but it's an entirely different build tool that is not used in Linux kernel build process. Usually `cmake` is just a "pre-processor" that produces the real Makefile, so when building an application that uses `cmake`, you would typically first run `cmake`, then `make`, then `make install`. But that is not relevant to Linux kernel.)

Comment: I was trying to use a command like make –C KERNEL_MODULE_BUILD_SYSTEM_FOLDER M=`pwd` module.  I just updated to Kernel 5.11.5 , I was trying to build a wifi driver  as an external module and install it using modprobe, I did not want to compile the complete kernel.

Comment: But it looks like the `mt7921` directory does not contain source code for a complete module: it becomes just a part of the `mt76.ko` module. A complete module will have a `MODULE_LICENSE()` line and some `EXPORT_SYMBOL[_GPL]()` lines: the files in the `mt7921` don't contain any of those.